# How to run a JSF 2.2 page in Java EE 7 environment without web.xml?

Tags: jsf, web.xml, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

What is wrong with my very very simple web app: web app successfully deployed to app server but hello bean did not inject to index.xhtml page 
(page shows just Hello from Facelets: #{hello.value})?

(this is first time when I am working with JSF, so maybe this question is very easy, and also I used good article http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/08/minimal-3-tier-java-ee-app-without-any.html )

I have the next structure of war archive:

```
mywebapp
|
 - WEB_INF
  |
   - classes
     |
      - Hello.class
 - index.html
```

Hello.java has:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Hello {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return "Hello JSF";
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and also my index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>My Facelet Page Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets: #{hello.value}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

For building project I used pom.xml:

```
....
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Simple web app</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have added web.xml to WEB-INF where I wrote configuration for Faces Servlet as I found in this file https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee7/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
and my web app now is working, but I still do not understand how to run it without web.xml?

Comment: Please paste the entire content of `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from **JavaServerFaces 2.0, The Complete Reference**:

> An entry in the Web application’s web.xml file enables the Faces Controller servlet
>      when a certain URL pattern is specified, such as /faces/. When running JSF 2.0 on
>      a Servlet 3.0 container, such as Sun’s Glassfish v3, the web.xml is optional. If no
>      web.xml is found, the Faces Controller servlet is automatically mapped to the most
>      popular URL patterns: /faces/, .jsf, and .faces.

So you should try with something like this:

`localhost:8080/mywebapp/faces/index.xhtml`.

Comment: yep you are right, I missed automatically mapping of Faces Controller)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [*javadoc*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html), `FacesServlet` will be automatically registered if any of the following conditions are true:

- A *`faces-config.xml`* file is found in *`WEB-INF`*
- A *`faces-config.xml`* file is found in the *`META-INF`* directory of a jar in the application's classpath.
- A filename ending in *`.faces-config.xml`* is found in the `META-INF` directory of a jar in the application's classpath.
- The `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES` context param is declared in *`web.xml`* or *`web-fragment.xml`*.
- The `Set` of classes passed to the `onStartup()` method of the `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation is not empty.

If you are using *`web.xml`* only for registering `FacesServlet`, then it would be optional if any of the above conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks Arun Gupta, actually I was reading your book "Java EE 7 Essentials" and trying to check example with JSF 2.2. For me it was first time with JSF.

Comment: Cool, All the samples from the book are available at: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples